# Php LiveDocx library or another template based pdf creation lib

Tags: pdf-generation, livedocx

I need to generate gift vouchers from PHP code and was looking at PDF libraries to accomplish this. Stumbled upon LiveDocx http://www.livedocx.com/ which looks like an excellent service and then found http://www.phplivedocx.org/ which looks like the natural choice for PHP. Problem is I'm using Zend Framework 1.6 still. Is there a way to get phplivedocx to work with Zend 1.6 or is there another template based php generation library that I can use?

Any other suggestions on accomplishing my original goal of generating vouchers is welcome although I must say that I've gone the programmatic approach before using TCPDF. It works well but is just too much work to get nice pdf design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up generating an HTML file and converting it with the wkhtmltopdf (Webkit HTML to Pdf) tool: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

If using a WYSIWYG editor to generate the HTML then I guess one is almost at the kind of functionality that livedocx brings i.e. to allow templates to be created with an editor.

Answer (score 0):

The zend framework is loosely coupled. You should try downloaded the latest copy and placing the Zend_Service_LiveDocX folder in your Zend library in the Zend_Services folder and if you have autoloading enabled, your application should be able to find it and use it... it's worth a try and certainly a better idea than sourcing another third party application.  I too have used all the various pdf libraries out there for php and you know what, I hated every one of them.